# What is opposite of electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, molecules

A negatively charged molecule will generate a field, an [electric field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field), and it will repel all negative ions.

So what does positively charged molecule generates that causes other positive molecules to be repelled?

Answer (score 0):

It's still called the electric field.  It just now has a positive sign instead of a negative sign.

Comment: so there are 2 types of electric fields one is positive and one is negative.

Comment: Yes, you can think of it that way.  But more generally, it is called simply "the electric field" and its sign, magnitude, and relation to position all depend on the source charges and where the charges are.  For more details, look at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefie.html.  The sign of $Q_source$ is what changes the sign of the electric field.

Comment: i've heard that magnetic field and electric field co-exist. So what is the sign of those electric field, source being normal everyday magnet.

Comment: They co-exist in the sense that both fields depend on the charge of the particle and they also depend on each other.  Google "Maxwell's equations" for details.  Electromagnetism is a huge subject and can't be taught via the comment section.  As for normal everyday magnets, to understand those is also a rather large subject (Google "Ferromagnetism").  Lastly, everyday magnets don't generate an electric field (they have no net charge) unless you run a current of electrons through them.